# r - plotting lines with mapview - automatically connects inaccurately

Tags: r, plot, maps, lines, r-sf

I`m trying to plot flights with mapview::mapview() but I have this problem where mapview automatically connects flights with straight lines if they go from Australia towards South America (across the Pacific Ocean), or from Russia to Canada (across the North pole) - see image below. Can this be fixed somehow?  Removing the straight lines artificially introduced would solve my problem, but other ideas and suggestions are welcomed
:[image: image here]

Comment: A similar question [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48857748/5977215)

Comment: Please see my answer to your question [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues/131#issuecomment-369891447)